# Can we synchronize string builder?

Tags: java

Java provide three string manipulation classes `String,StringBuilder and StringBuffer`.
In which `StringBuilder` is not synchronize and `StringBuffer` is synchronize.

So I just want to ask is there a possibility to synchronize `StringBuilder`.

Comment: When StringBuffer is already there you you want to synchronize StringBuilder??

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: we can synchronize on any object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just synchronise externally, either by using `synchronized` blocks or manually when you access the `StringBuilder` from multiple threads.

But why would you want to? You have `StringBuffer` already.

Answer (score 2):

Quote

> This class [StringBuilder] provides an API compatible with
>   StringBuffer, but with no guarantee of synchronization. This class is
>   designed for use as a drop-in replacement for StringBuffer in places
>   where the string buffer was being used by a single thread (as is
>   generally the case). Where possible, it is recommended that this class
>   be used in preference to StringBuffer as it will be faster under most
>   implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If you know StringBuffer is synchronized, why do you need synchronize StringBuilder?

I supposed you can extend StringBuilder, and create a synchronized method which calls the un-synchronized methods

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with the help of locking mechanism like `synchronized` method or block or `Reentrantlock`.

`StringBuffer` is already existed it is recommanded to use that one.

Answer (score 0):

Of course ..You can synchronize `StringBuilder` but `StringBuffer` is already present in API which is synchronized.

`StringBuffer` has all methods synchronized for data manipulation methods(`insert()`,`append()` etc.) as well as data reading methods(`indexOf()`,`subSequence()`,`toString()` etc.).

By synchronizing, only a specific block of code which you want to be thread safe while using `StringBuilder`, I think you could gain some performance.